# Cannot send link in Rails with Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app that sends a invitation email containing a link to register. But the register link gives an error. The email will send if the register link is not there.

```
NoMethodError in Invitations#create
undefined method `accept_referral_invitation_url' for #(#(Class:0xadd8c90):0xb5d868cc)
```

the error is happening on this line

```
= accept_referral_invitation_url(@invitation.invite_token)
```

**InvitationsController**

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @invitation = Invitation.new
    end

  def create
  @invitation = current_user.invitations.new(params[:invitation])

    if @invitation.valid?
      @invitation.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Invitation sent!"
      UserMailer.invitation(@invitation).deliver
    else
      render "new", :notice => "Somehting went wrong!"
    end
end


  def accept_referral
      @invitation = Invitation.find_by_invite_token(params[:invite_token])
      @invitation.accepted_at = Time.zone.now
      @invitation.save!
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Success!"
  end

end
```

**User Mailer**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def invitation(invitation)
    @invitation = invitation
    mail(:to => invitation.email, :subject => "You're invited", :from => 'alain@lootfly.com')
  end
end
```

**invitation.html.haml** (message that gets sent)

```
You have been cordially invited to join beta.
Click this link to sign up!
= accept_referral_invitation_url(@invitation.invite_token)
= accept_referral_invitation_url(invite_token: @invitation.invite_token)
# I TRIED BOTH OF THOSE LINKS^^^^ TO NO AVAIL!!!!!!!
```

**invitations model**

```
  create_table "invitations", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.text     "email"
    t.text     "invite_token"
  end
```

**EDIT: Rake routes**

```
        invitations GET    /invitations(.:format)                invitations#index
                    POST   /invitations(.:format)                invitations#create
     new_invitation GET    /invitations/new(.:format)            invitations#new
    edit_invitation GET    /invitations/:id/edit(.:format)       invitations#edit
         invitation GET    /invitations/:id(.:format)            invitations#show
                    PUT    /invitations/:id(.:format)            invitations#update
                    DELETE /invitations/:id(.:format)            invitations#destroy
```

Comment: paste the output of `rake routes` please

Comment: Try it without calling .invite_token on @invitation?

Comment: I'm curious about the `Invitations` (plural, upper case) object referenced in the error message. Do you know where that's coming from? Would you share your `Invitation` class definition?

Comment: calling it without .invite_token on invitation does not change anything @fabsays and -shime i added the output of rake routes to op. and peter alfvin in my user model it's called.... class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :accepted_at, :invite_token, :email, :sent_by, :sent_to

Comment: i got it with the help of @PeterAlfvin and shime. both set the in the right path. Can you both put answers so i can check mark one and +1 the other. THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing this in config/routes.rb

```
resources :invitations do
  get 'accept_referral', :on => :collection 
end
```

That will generate a GET target like /invitations/accept_referral that will accept an invitation, so you can do

```
accept_referral_invitations_url()
```

Now, to get the invitation code, do:

```
accept_referral_invitations_url(:invite_token => @invitation.invite_token)
```

Which will result in a URL like /invitations/accept_referral?invite_token=blahblahblah

Note that I added the GET target on the collection (not the member), so I don't need to pass the @invitation object itself.  And, because it's a collection target, you use invitations_url (plural) not invitation_url.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

The `Invitations` object in your error is suspicious, since Rails normally wouldn't create a class of that name (i.e. plural with no qualifier). You should check your `Invitation` class definition for an improper use of that object name.

Comment: So was the `Invitations` reference valid? Was it just a routes problem or was there a problem elsewhere?